How to move action button into area where it may be obscured by a dropdown menu?
In the below R Shiny code, the below HTML/CSS section at the top of the ui is very important in keeping the width of the sidebar panel fixed while the main panel contracts/expands to match the window size as the user adjusts the window, while allowing certain objects like plots to automatically adjust in size, both expanding and contracting (it works great, I don't want to lose this functionality):
tags$head(
      tags$style(HTML("
      .sidebar {
        flex-shrink: 0;
      }
      .main-panel {
        flex-grow: 1;
        margin-left: 20px;
        resize: both;
        overflow: auto;
      }
      .main-panel > div {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
    "))
    )

However, this above code snippet and the overflow = "visible" specification in the rhandsontable() function in the server section cause the "Add series" action button to be placed far below the user input table hottable_1, as shown in the below image. I comment out either of the above and I either lose the important fixed sidebar panel and adjustable size main panel/plots, or the dropdown menu in the second row of input table hottable_1 is truncated when the user clicks on it. But if I comment out either of the above the action button in correctly placed under hottable_1.

How can I move the "Add series" action button so it is placed immediately beneath hottable_1, while keeping the functionality of the above HTML/CSS snippet and not truncating the dropdown menu when the user clicks on it? Preferable the dropdown would cover part of the action button; once the user makes the dropdown selection the dropdown retracts anyway revealing the action button.
Code:
library(jsonlite)
library(rhandsontable)
library(shiny)

ui <- 
  fluidPage(
    tags$head(
      tags$style(HTML("
      .sidebar {
        flex-shrink: 0;
      }
      .main-panel {
        flex-grow: 1;
        margin-left: 20px;
        resize: both;
        overflow: auto;
      }
      .main-panel > div {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
    "))
    ),
    titlePanel(""),
    div(
      style = "display: flex; align-items: flex-start;",
      div(class = "sidebar",wellPanel()),
      div(
        class = "main-panel",
        "Parent tab", value = 'parent_tab',
          tabsetPanel(
            tabPanel(
              "Child tab",
              rHandsontableOutput('hottable_1'),
              actionButton("addSeries","Add series"),
            )
          )
      )
    )
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  seriesTbl_1 <- reactiveVal(
    data.frame(
      'Series1' = c(1, NA_character_),
      row.names = c("Row_A", "Row_B")
    )
  )
  
  choiceSelect <- toJSON(c('Choice A', 'Choice B', 'Choice C', 'Choice D', 'Choice E'))
  
  observeEvent(input$hottable_1, {
    seriesTbl_1(hot_to_r(input$hottable_1))
    tbl <- seriesTbl_1()
  })
  
  output$hottable_1 <- renderRHandsontable({
    tbl <- seriesTbl_1()
    colNames <- paste0("Series", 1:ncol(tbl))
    colnames(tbl) <- colNames
    rhandsontable(
      tbl,
      overflow = "visible"
    ) %>%
      hot_table(id = "hottable_1") %>%
      htmlwidgets::onRender(sprintf("
        function(el, x) {
          var hot = this.hot;
          var listElements = %s;
          hot.updateSettings({
            cells: function (row, col, prop) {
              var cellProperties = {};
              if (row === 1) {  
                cellProperties.type = 'dropdown';
                cellProperties.source = listElements;
              } 
              return cellProperties;
            }
          });
        }
      ", choiceSelect))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$addSeries, {
    newSeriesCol_1 <- data.frame(c(1, NA_character_))
    names(newSeriesCol_1) <- paste("Series", ncol(seriesTbl_1()) + 1)
    seriesTbl_1(cbind(seriesTbl_1(), newSeriesCol_1))
  })
  
  seriesTbl_1_DF <- reactive({
    tbl <- seriesTbl_1()
    colNames <- paste0("Series", 1:ncol(tbl))
    colnames(tbl) <- colNames
    tbl
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)


You could use {shinyjs} to hide the table div when it has invalid values (i.e. when it's empty), so that the button would move upwards when the table is hidden, and below the table with its visible. That being said, it seems to me that you could achieve the same app UI in way less code using fluidRow and column or other stablished app building framework.

Seems like rhandsontable was defaulting to 30px row height, and has a 30px header row; I added height param to the rhandsontable call, and it seemed to be what you want.
 rhandsontable(
      tbl,
      overflow = "visible",
      height = 30+nrow(tbl)*30 # <<<---- limit the total height
    )


Such a simple and clean solution, and so much for me to learn!
